# Divergence of Groups and Metric Spaces

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, mg.metric-geometry, geometric-group-theory

Several papers, including [this](https://www.math.lsu.edu/~pdani/research/racg-div.pdf) and [this](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/953d/46f0add69b53d87e46303cc8f3b3184e67b0.pdf) claim that divergence of finitely generated groups and metric spaces have been introduced by Misha Gromov in his paper "Asymptotic invariants of infinite groups". What is the precise reference and how did Gromov call this invariant?

Comment: It is really annoying that some authors quote a result contained in a 194-pages long paper, without saying the *precise* place where it can be found.

Comment: It is especially true for Gromov's papers where it is not always immediately clear what he is talking about. The paradox is that after it is explained, one feels that the interpretation is very clear and  the only reasonable one.

Comment: "A really good idea is one that is obvious, after someone else explains it to you" - Anonymous- :)

Comment: In a quick look at the book I can't locate any allusion to divergence. Have you asked the authors of these linked papers?

Answer (score 4):

Here is (what I believe is) the relevant paragraph of the second "this", of which I am one of the co-authors. This paragraph contains a reference to a particular passage from Gromov's Asymptotic Invariants paper including a citation to the particular paragraph in that paper where the relevant discussion occurs.

*In symmetric spaces of non-compact type, the order of the divergence of
geodesic rays is either exponential (when the rank is one) or linear (when the
rank is at least two). This inspired an initial thought that in the presence
of non-positive curvature the divergence must be either linear or exponential.
See [Gro93] for a discussion—an explicit statement of this conjecture appears
in 6.B2, subsection “Geometry of ∂T and Morse landscape at infinity,” Example
(h). In particular, Gromov stated an expectation that all pairs of geodesic
rays in the universal cover of a closed Riemannian manifold of non-positive
curvature diverge either linearly or exponentially [Gro93].*

Comment: This does not answer my question, unfortunately. Gromov did not define divergence of groups or metric spaces in 6. $B_2$. I think the correct answer is "Gromov did not define divergence functions of groups or metric spaces, but a comment in 6.$B_2$ inspired Gersten to give a definition".

Comment: In a sense this answers your question, which asks what is the part of Gromov's book that is aimed by these references. Based on this, you have the right to judge what is the part of Gromov's contribution to the definition of divergence (I'm curious what is the intended meaning that "two geodesic rays diverge exponentially").

Comment: From personal experience, I would not be surprised that Gromov discussed this topic verbally with someone (Gersten?) to an unknown extent and precision. He may have even asked the specific question about the divergence function. When that person asked Gromov for a reference, he may have pointed to this paragraph, but the content of the discussion was probably richer than the content of the reference.

Comment: I have asked Misha Gromov yesterday, and he said he did not define the divergence of groups or metric spaces in that book.

Comment: As far as I understand, the divergence of two geodesic length-parametrised rays $r_1(t)$, $r_2(t)$ which Gromov discusses in 6.$B_2$  (where $r_1(0)=r_2(0)=o$) is the function $d(t)$ which is the distance between $r_1(t)$ and $r_2(t)$ in the space with open ball $B(o,t)$  removed. I think it is a standard notion in differential geometry (that is the meaning of the phrase that  hyperbolic space-time is exponentially expanding).